# find all users of a certain role and return that list

Tags: users, entities, database

I am trying to turn this query to drupal EntityCondition query

```
select u.name, ',', u.mail, ',', r.name , ','
from users as u, users_roles as ur, role as r 
where u.uid = ur.uid 
and ur.rid = r.rid
```

This should return a list of all users with their email username and user role

I have this

```
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery;
  $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
    ->addTag('role_filter');
  $results = $query2->execute();
```

So getting all users within a specific role id

```
function mymodule_query_role_filter_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->leftJoin('users_roles', 'r', 'users.uid = r.uid');  
  $and = db_and()
            ->condition('r.rid', array(3,4,5), 'IN');
  $query
    ->condition($and);
}
```

I am not sure how to get the role value based on what I have
is it another entity condition?

The above entityFiledQuery does return the following

```
{"1":{"uid":"1","name":"admin","pass":"HASHPASSWORD!","mail":"admin@example.com" "roles":{"2":"authenticated user","3":"administrator"},
```

but 
a) I would rather have roles as the value administrator and not this funky array with the "rid" key
b) the hashed password is there, can data be sanitized ?

Comment: Isn't naming your module "users" rather confusing given that the core module is named "user"?

Comment: Yeah, I would change that for clarity.

Comment: It has another name, I just cannot use it publicly so I changed it to users
we can call it 
XYZ_query_role as well

Comment: Oh in that case, a general practice is using `mymodule_` as a prefix (or `mytheme_` for themes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the role is in the `role` table so just join that in as well:

```
function mymodule_query_role_filter_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->innerJoin('users_roles', 'ur', 'users.uid = ur.uid');  
  $query->innerJoin('role', 'r', 'r.rid = ur.rid');
  $query->condition('r.name', 'administrator');
}
```

Note that you want inner joins here, not left, otherwise you'll just get whether they have the admin role or not. You don't need an `and` as you only have one condition.

The hashed password is added by `user_load`, not your query, so you'd have to address that separately. I'm not sure there's an easy way to exclude a property from an entity load, it would make for a good follow-up question.

Comment: $query->condition('r.name', 'administrator');
there are 3 types of roles I don't want to limit this to administrator only

Comment: So apply what you already know ;) `$query->condition('r.name', ['administrator', 'foo', 'bar'], 'IN');`

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the entity_load still returns role as "roles":{"2":"authenticated user","3":"administrator"} so when I parse the data I have to do something like roles[1] which is not super great programmatically

Comment: You already have the roles up front, you're limiting the query results by those roles...why would you need to get them from the user entity? You already know they're going to be correct right? If you desperately need to check again with php just use `array_search` if you need to find the role ID, or `in_array` to test that the user has a certain role

Comment: Or `reset` to get the first, `end` to get the last, `array_slice` to get a certain other one, `array_filter` if you're feeling fruity, the list goes on. It feels like there's probably some context missing from your question that would clear this up. In plain English what are you trying to do? Get all users with any of these roles and do x with them? Get all users with all of these roles and do y with them? Something else?

Comment: The ideas is to create a list of all users in a table so the table will have : 
User_name, user_email, user_role

by getting [foo,bar,faz] I am getting all users on the site of these 3 types
now I have to list them witht the right role

Comment: You don't really need anything Drupal-specific to do that, although the Views module comes to mind, what you're doing would take 2 minutes with that and have the added benefit of not loading the password column into memory if that's indeed a concern. A simple `explode($user->roles, ', ')` will create a comma-separated string of the roles for example

Comment: That would be true, but I need to get the information from 3 different sites to a centralize site

My idea was to write a custom module in the centralized site and another api module for the 3 sites

so the centralized sites invokes the query function in the sites that have that module enabled

Comment: Is there away to programmatically get the data from a view with say drupal_http_request ?